# How can I get a liberty server.xml variable in java?

Tags: java, environment-variables, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to set a `server.xml` variable during runtime.

Therefore, I need an environment variable that I can use inside my `server.xml` e.g. `${variable}` and in my java code e.g. `System.getProperty`.

A simple `<variable name="test" value="4325" />` works in my `server.xml` but I cannot read this value in Java.

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>
<library id="messageHubLoginLib">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}" includes="messagehub.login-1.0.0.jar"/>
</library>

<jaasLoginModule id="KafkaClient" className="com.ibm.messagehub.login.MessageHubLoginModule" controlFlag="REQUIRED" libraryRef="messageHubLoginLib">
    <options serviceName="kafka" username="#USERNAME" password="#PASSWORD"/>
</jaasLoginModule>

<jaasLoginContextEntry id="KafkaClient" name="KafkaClient" loginModuleRef="KafkaClient"  />
```

I would like during runtine to update the values of `#USERNAME` and `#PASSWORD` in the `server.xml` file. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, as a workaround I've read the server.xml as XML doc, manipulate the entries and write it back to server.xml

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code? We can't help a lot in this way...
However i suggest you to use a library for .xml files like JAXB and unmarshall and marshall the .xml file when you need to reada or write on it.

Comment: I think the TP does not have any code yet, as he is asking for a valid strategy to modify the application server's config file at runtime through his java application.